# What is a hop bill?

Tags: hops, recipe

There is of course beer recipes but what makes it different from a hop bill? Do you use a hop bill for all types of beers? What do you consider when making one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The term "Bill": be it grain or hops is simply the list of that type of ingredient, weight and time or stage schedule and how it's applied to the recipe.

Sample:
2oz Galaxy FWH

( weight, ingredient, added to kettle allowing the first wort of the sparge to mix with the hops, hops stay in for full duration of the boil)

Yes all beers have a grain and hop bill, technically. Even if each bill just has one ingedient.

Comment: Just to add, I would also write down the alpha acids for each hop variety used and (if available) oil content as well as beta acids. Since one of the goals of a recipe is repeatability, knowing the bittering power of all hops used can help in recreating the beer at a later point in time with a different batch of hops.